# Given $\forall X\, p(X)$, use the Fitch System to prove $\lnot \exists X\, \lnot p(X)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I've tried to solve this exercise based on a similar question that was asked some years ago, but I'm stuck in step 5.
Any help? Thanks in advance.
By the way I'm using [Stanford's system](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php).

```
1.  AX:p(X)            Premise
2.  ~p(X)              Assumption
3.  EX:p(X)            Assumption
4.  ~p(X)              Reiteration: 2
5.  EX:p(X) => ~p(X)   Implication Introduction: 3, 4
```

Comment: Try working backwards. The statement you're trying to prove is a negation, so your proof will end with a negation introduction. This negation introduction will be justified by a sub-proof that makes an assumption (of the statement you're trying to negate) and derives a contradiction. Figure out what the assumption should be and then use quantifier elimination rules in the sub-proof to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you *assume* $\exists x \,\lnot P(x)$ and show that it leads to a contradiction with the premise $\forall x \, P(x)$, by means of  the rules for the elimination of existential and universal quantifiers. This means that the *negation* of the assumption  $\exists x \,\lnot P(x)$ holds.

This intuition is a little watered-down in [Stanford's platform](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) because its rules for [negation introduction](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/section.php?section=section_04_04) and [existential elimination](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/section.php?section=section_08_03) are slightly clumsy and unusual for natural deduction.

Anyway, the correct formalization of a proof of $\lnot \exists x \, \lnot P(x)$ from $\forall x \, P(x)$ in the Fitch-style natural deduction system implemented by Stanford's platform is the following: [image]

Comment: Taroccoesbrocco you're awesome, thank you!